Confusing! The number of teeth on a ring gear in a planetary gear system
I watched the video https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Xw5X3YXnkns.
The teeth numbers of Ring/Planet/Sun are 68/24/19.
68 ≠ 2 × 24 + 19
Why?
How can the Planet Gear System be assembled?
Profile shifted gears or other method can satisfy the condition?

Gears mesh if the size and pitch of the teeth match.

Where did you get the gear tooth counts from?
